# Is there a reason why a differential solid angle is represented by a cone?

Tags: solid-angle

Just wondering... is there a geometric reason why a differential solid angle is usually represented by a cone? I cannot see that given the formula

$$
d\Omega = \sin \theta \, d\theta \, d\phi
$$

I cannot see that.